# PHP Form Submit and Parsing

Tags: php, forms, parsing

I am looking to use PHP to get a few random paragraphs from this site:
http://watchout4snakes.com/CreativityTools/RandomParagraph/RandomParagraph.aspx

What's the shortest set of code to initiate the Submit button (don't need to fill in the text fields) and parse out only the resultant random text?

Can't seem to get the submit piece to work.

Comment: What have you tried ? What do mean by "initiate" ? Do you mean trigger from the submit button ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More flexible way - fetch viewstate and eventvalidation dynamically:

```
<?php
$url = 'http://watchout4snakes.com/CreativityTools/RandomParagraph/RandomParagraph.aspx';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1; .NET CLR 1.0.3705; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; Media Center PC 4.0)'); 
$c = curl_exec($ch); 
curl_close($ch); 

//__VIEWSTATE
$viewstate = '';

//__EVENTVALIDATION
$eventvalidation = '';

// Fetch VIEWSTATE
$p1 = '<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="';
$p = strpos($c, $p1);
if ($p !== false) {
    $s = substr($c, $p+strlen($p1));
    $pcs = explode('"', $s);
    if (!empty($pcs[0])) {
        $viewstate = $pcs[0];
    }
}

// Fetch EVENTVALIDATION
$p1 = '<input type="hidden" name="__EVENTVALIDATION" id="__EVENTVALIDATION" value="';
$p = strpos($c, $p1);
if ($p !== false) {
    $s = substr($c, $p+strlen($p1));
    $pcs = explode('"', $s);
    if (!empty($pcs[0])) {
        $eventvalidation = $pcs[0];
    }
}

// PUT YOUR OBJECT & SUBJECT HERE
$postvalues = array(
    'tmpl$main$txtSubject' => '',
    'tmpl$main$txtObject' => '',
    'tmpl$main$btnNew' => 'New Paragraph',
);

$url = 'http://watchout4snakes.com/CreativityTools/RandomParagraph/RandomParagraph.aspx?__VIEWSTATE='.urlencode($viewstate).'&__EVENTVALIDATION='.urlencode($eventvalidation).'&tmpl%24main%24txtSubject='.urlencode($postalues['tmpl$main$txtSubject']).'&tmpl%24main%24txtObject='.urlencode($postalues['tmpl$main$txtObject']).'&tmpl%24main%24btnNew=New%20Paragraph';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1; .NET CLR 1.0.3705; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; Media Center PC 4.0)'); 
$c = curl_exec($ch); 
curl_close($ch); 


$t = '<span id="tmpl_main_lblPara" class="randomSentence">';
$p = strpos($c, $t);
if ($p !== false) {
    $s = substr($c, $p + strlen($t));
    $pcs = explode('</span>', $s);


   echo $pcs[0]; 
}
```

Comment: Output seems to be including "<span id="tmpl_main_lblPara" class="randomSentence">"

Answer (score 1):

Try simply to POST the page.
Or GET this url [http://watchout4snakes.com/CreativityTools/RandomParagraph/RandomParagraph.aspx?_*VIEWSTATE=%2FwEPDwUINTQyOTcxOTkPZBYCZg9kFgQCAg9kFgICAQ9kFgICAQ9kFgQCBw8PFgIeBFRleHRlZGQCCQ8PFgQfAGUeB1Zpc2libGVoZGQCAw8PFgIfAAU4Q29weXJpZ2h0IDIwMDcgd2F0Y2hvdXQ0c25ha2VzLmNvbS4gQWxsIFJpZ2h0cyBSZXNlcnZlZC5kZGTorXr6Gf6R0THMyZRJWZJWtrWHYw%3D%3D&*_EVENTVALIDATION=%2FwEWBAKs0KOMDAKf643lBALimIbkBQLx2ZbtAfvuWUuGYHixchu%2FJnnxDjXxcnqg&tmpl%24main%24txtSubject=&tmpl%24main%24txtObject=&tmpl%24main%24btnNew=New+Paragraph](http://watchout4snakes.com/CreativityTools/RandomParagraph/RandomParagraph.aspx?__VIEWSTATE=/wEPDwUINTQyOTcxOTkPZBYCZg9kFgQCAg9kFgICAQ9kFgICAQ9kFgQCBw8PFgIeBFRleHRlZGQCCQ8PFgQfAGUeB1Zpc2libGVoZGQCAw8PFgIfAAU4Q29weXJpZ2h0IDIwMDcgd2F0Y2hvdXQ0c25ha2VzLmNvbS4gQWxsIFJpZ2h0cyBSZXNlcnZlZC5kZGTorXr6Gf6R0THMyZRJWZJWtrWHYw==&__EVENTVALIDATION=/wEWBAKs0KOMDAKf643lBALimIbkBQLx2ZbtAfvuWUuGYHixchu/JnnxDjXxcnqg&tmpl%24main%24txtSubject=&tmpl%24main%24txtObject=&tmpl%24main%24btnNew=New%20Paragraph)

You will need just to fetch `span.randomSentence` content.
[This](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) can help to do it.

**EDIT**
Code I've tested:

```
$url = 'http://watchout4snakes.com/CreativityTools/RandomParagraph/RandomParagraph.aspx?__VIEWSTATE=/wEPDwUINTQyOTcxOTkPZBYCZg9kFgQCAg9kFgICAQ9kFgICAQ9kFgQCBw8PFgIeBFRleHRlZGQCCQ8PFgQfAGUeB1Zpc2libGVoZGQCAw8PFgIfAAU4Q29weXJpZ2h0IDIwMDcgd2F0Y2hvdXQ0c25ha2VzLmNvbS4gQWxsIFJpZ2h0cyBSZXNlcnZlZC5kZGTorXr6Gf6R0THMyZRJWZJWtrWHYw==&__EVENTVALIDATION=/wEWBAKs0KOMDAKf643lBALimIbkBQLx2ZbtAfvuWUuGYHixchu/JnnxDjXxcnqg&tmpl%24main%24txtSubject=&tmpl%24main%24txtObject=&tmpl%24main%24btnNew=New%20Paragraph';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1; .NET CLR 1.0.3705; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; Media Center PC 4.0)'); 
$c = curl_exec($ch); 
curl_close($ch); 

$p = strpos($c, '<span id="tmpl_main_lblPara" class="randomSentence">');
if ($p !== false) {
    $s = substr($c, $p);
    $pcs = explode('</span>', $s);
    echo $pcs[0];
}
```

Comment: How did you get the full URL with viewstate etc?

Comment: Posted the form and saw fields in firebug. I see in is not working now. I will provide you more flexible solution if you need. Do you?

Comment: See below.. Should work. Tell me if it doesn't. Thats a robust code, add some validation etc there before using it.